# How to stay interested in Eve Online?

Tags: eve-online

Eve is a game with spaceships. Spaceships are awesome, and they look quite cool in the game. There are even lasers, missiles and drones. More awesome.

I really want to get into the game, but it hasn't worked out for me so far. I've tried trial three or four times over the past three years, I know the game pretty well for a trial player, including a few tricks that'd let me get the rumored "plex within fourteen days". However, I just get bored between my first and third week every time. Combat is boring, often leading to the game being called in jest "spreadsheets in space". The novelty simply wears off after a while, but I really want to start liking this game.

I know I'm supposed to find a player corp, supposedly it's nigh-impossible to play solo. I also know that it's good to set a goal for myself, as unlike themepark MMOs, Eve doesn't serve the player a premade motivation. I've never done the former (except for the Uni which let me play solo and provided me with lessons), and I've had trouble coming up with the latter. Are there any other tips to liking Eve, or any other tips to finding a goal in the game?

Comment: I think this question would be better asked as 'what is there to do in EVE Online'.

Comment: This may be a "soft" question, but it's an important one. Eve is a *hard* game to get into. Specific expertise from an experienced Eve player would be useful here.

Comment: while very open, i strongly support this question.

Comment: Yes, I agree. As beyond spending ages flying around Eve is hella boring.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ohai! Srs Internet Spaceship captain, here!

EVE is ultimately a game about setting your own goals and taking satisfaction in achieving them. Nothing else matters. Not your killboard score, nor the amount of ISK in your wallet, not even your spaceship fame. Not unless you make them your goals. And believe me, those are the *really* boring ones.

On goals themselves, there are two broad and inaccurate categories for them: in-game and meta-game goals. Former would include anything that somehow affects the gameworld - accumulate X ISK, build a corp with Y members, etc. Latter would include visiting every system in the cluster, collecting one of EVERY item (looking at you, Entity) in the game, figuring you what the heck is the big Sleeper mystery  or learning everything there is to learn about every game mechanic, effectively becoming an living EVE encyclopedia.

IMO, metas are much more interesting, but to each their own. Again, I want to reiterate the importance of taking satisfaction in achieving your goals.

[This](http://swiftandbitter.com/eve/wtd/) should give you some ideas.

Comment: Wow, great link, and a good answer in general. Gonna wait a day and accept this :)

Comment: This is one of the better ways I've seen to describe the game play EVE online.  It is a game where you define your own goals, be they short term or long term.  It's also spoiled me from any other sandbox games as when I play other games now, I want some direction.  LOL.

Answer (score 7):

You already addressed one of the ways to get ahead in EVE - join a corp.  I played EVE a long time ago but never got into a corp and got lost and bored easily, so I quit.  I recently went back to EVE because I got tired of the same theme park MMOs, and wanted to tackle a harder learning curve.

Two things that kept me around (currently taking a break because of new job) were my interest in industry and the fact that I found a good corp in a good alliance. We do everything from PVE to PVP, but we are not so hardcore that you feel pressured to do anything.  It is a lot easier to get interested in the content when there are people to support and help you learn how to get around in game.

EVE is hit or miss with many people.  Some people just hate the structure while others love it.  It is easy to get overwhelmed by the learning curve and discouraged by the mentality of some of the more hardcore players.  But if you do find a place in EVE, it can be very enjoyable and pretty addictive.

Comment: Pretty much everyone sane who stays in the NPC corps will always find it eventually boring. Joining a Player Corp is by far the best thing you could do. jb11 here has pretty much the same story as my Eve history.